# Documentation: What is the simile for non code tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, documentation

I want to contribute to `amazon-web-services` (and its subgroups) documentation and I would like to do it correctly: What is the analogy of code snippets in this case? Should I make a full sample of let's say, a service and paste screenshots? As of the main documentation, is it better to reference official aws blogs, documentation i.e., any links or should I bring all of it and create content here?